# How do I limit the amount of checkbox checked with JavaScript(no jquery please)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I'm making a Node Express multiple choice test, and each question has different amount of correct answers. I have my answers coming from a database auto-populate in PUG. However my Function doesn't work right, when I click over the limit of correct answers, the alert pops up but then the answer is checked anyways. What am I doing wrong?

I tried making a function that tracks how many answers checked, but can't get it to stop after it reaches the limit.

```
block content
    header.header USA Government Test
    main.q-card
        p.q-promt #{question} 
            small (Please choose #{mcLimit} answers)
        hr
        each answer in answers
            label.container
                | #{answer.Answer_prompt}
                input(type='checkbox' name='answer' onclick="ckLimit()")
                span.checkmark
            hr
    script.
        function ckLimit() {
            var limit = #{mcLimit};
            var total = 0;
            var inputTag = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
            var x = inputTag.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < x; i++) {
                if (inputTag[i].checked) {
                    total += 1;
                }
                if (total > limit) {
                    alert(`Please select only ${limit}`);
                    this.checked = false;
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
```

everything works accept the: this.checked = false;
It continues to check answers. This what my code looks like now:

```
    header.header USA Government Test
    main.q-card
        p.q-promt #{question} 
            small (Please choose #{mcLimit} answers)
        hr
        each answer in answers
            label.container
                | #{answer.Answer_prompt}
                input(type='checkbox' name='answer' onclick="return ckLimit()")
                span.checkmark
            hr
    script.
        function ckLimit() {
            var limit = #{mcLimit};
            var total = 0;
            var inputTag = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
            var x = inputTag.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < x; i++) {
                if (inputTag[i].checked) {
                    total += 1;
                }
                if (total > limit) {
                    alert(`Please select only ${limit}`);
                    this.checked = false;
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `return` keyword to the below statement.

```
input(type='checkbox' name='answer' onclick="ckLimit()")
```

thus becoming

```
input(type='checkbox' name='answer' onclick="return ckLimit()")
```

Without `return`,  `onclick` proceeds on allowing the default action of checking. Once `onclick` gets `false` value, it stops the action.

---

Edit:

In function `ckLimit`, `return` should return `false`.

```
if (total > limit) {
    alert(`Please select only ${limit}`);
    this.checked = false;
    return false;   
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however it's still not working correctly. It still alerts that I reached the limit and then it continues to check the item.

Comment: Check edited portion. `return` should return `false`

Comment: I just saw this edit just now. Thanks for your help!!